# What if we migrate Machine-learning, and related tags question to datascience page?

Tags: discussion, status-declined, migration

I think in Stack Overflow, under machine learning and related tags questions are huge and I also observed that the to Data Science site is not crowded.

What if anyhow admin team migrate those Stack Overflow questions to Data Science.

Just a thought.

Comment: Move machine learning?! Hmmm... the machines will learn of this post and punish you.

Comment: did you ask at [DS.SE meta](http://meta.datascience.stackexchange.com/) what they think about this idea?

Answer (score 11):

No. Mass-moving of questions is not an option.

[Data Science](http://datascience.stackexchange.com) is a *beta site* and they need to discover what their site culture is going to be. A mass migration of posts from Stack Overflow to there would force the Stack Overflow culture on that site instead.

Moreover, this is not helpful to either the people that asked questions or those that answered the post. They did so in the context of Stack Overflow, and their posts would be treated differently on a different site. For older posts, many authors (if not most) will not be active enough anymore or remember the context enough to be able to actively participate on DS for those posts.

Note that the system currently prevents moderators from migrating posts to another site unless they are less than 60 days old for many of the same reasons.